# The argument types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to filter two different (Data Picker's) that are in the same column at the grid. I try to reach a command with these two fields. The whole filtering process is going on in the code behind, and so far it is working for the other fields in the grid. But for one I'm getting a strange exception:

> {"The argument types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. 
>   Near greater than or equals expression, line 6, column 15."}

In the DB the field is a datetime and it is a single column

My code :

```
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EntryDate" DataType="System.DateTime" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" FilterControlAltText="Filter EntryDate column"
                        HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="EntryDate" UniqueName="EntryDate" FilterControlWidth="50px">
                        <FilterTemplate>
                            From
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="FromOrderDatePicker" runat="server" Width="100px" AutoPostBack="true"
                                OnSelectedDateChanged="FromOrderDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" OnPreRender="FromOrderDatePicker_PreRender" />
                            to
                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="ToOrderDatePicker" runat="server" Width="100px" AutoPostBack="true"
                                OnSelectedDateChanged="ToOrderDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" OnPreRender="ToOrderDatePicker_PreRender" />

                        </FilterTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Code behind:

```
     protected void FromOrderDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.SelectedDateChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                RadDatePicker picker = sender as RadDatePicker;
                ViewState["FromDatePicker"] = DateTimeToString(picker.SelectedDate.Value);

                ExpressionChanged();
            }
            protected void FromOrderDatePicker_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (ViewState["FromDatePicker"] != null)
                {
                    RadDatePicker picker = sender as RadDatePicker;
                    picker.SelectedDate = StringToDateTime(ViewState["FromDatePicker"].ToString());
                }
            }


  private string DateTimeToString(DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.Month + "/" + dt.Day + "/" + dt.Year;
    }
    private DateTime StringToDateTime(string s)
    {
        string[] dts = s.Split('/');
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(dts[2]), Int32.Parse(dts[0]), Int32.Parse(dts[1]));
        return dt;
    }
```

It would be just redundant to post the code (for the toDatePicker)

```
 private void ExpressionChanged()
    {
        //reset
        TimeReportGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = null;
        TimeReportGrid.MasterTableView.Rebind();


        if (ViewState["FromDatePicker"] != null &&
            ViewState["ToDatePicker"] != null &&
            ViewState["FromDatePicker"].ToString() != "" &&
            ViewState["ToDatePicker"].ToString() != "")
        {
            TimeReportGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression += "(it.EntryDate >= '" + ViewState["FromDatePicker"].ToString() + "') AND (it.EntryDate <= '" + ViewState["ToDatePicker"].ToString() + "')";
        }
```

feel free to ask if there is any problem

Thanks for help and fast answer !

Comment: At a very quick glance it looks like you are trying to compare dates and strings together. I've not used expressions much but I assume it is your FilterExpression at the end. Can you parse the string to date first?

Comment: @Chris you mean i should pars the ViewState to date time  ?

Comment: I think so. I'm not used to expressions but it looks like you have something like `it.EntryDate >= '2013-05-14'` and something like `it.EntryDate >= DateTime.Parse('2013-05-14')` looks better. As I say though I've not done expressions so I am just giving you something to look at since I'm not really in a position to give you a solution (not sure if Edm.DateTime is something special for example or if it is compatible with DateTime)...

Comment: @Chris I really do appreciate that you are trying to help me but , it's also not working ..

Comment: Sorry, I've got to tag out then. The error is saying that its trying to compare strings and dates but how to fix that is beyond me. :(

Comment: @Chris the solution is pretty simple I had just to add a DATETIME declaration after the >= and it works '^^

Comment: Glad to hear it. You should put up an actual answer to this question (rather than just a comment) describing your answer with the code you changed so that you can mark it as the correct answer and anybody else coming to the question can find it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is pretty simple I just had to declared that EntryDateis a DATETIME that would look like that

```
TimeReportGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression += "(it.EntryDate>= DATETIME '" + ViewState["FromDatePicker"].ToString() + " 00:00') AND (it.EntryDate<= DATETIME '" + ViewState["ToDatePicker"].ToString() + " 23:59')";
```

Simple but take me some time to get it

Feel free to ask if there are any problems